# How to Use My IPad Webcam through a Remote Desktop

Tags: azure, remote-desktop

I need to use a desktop app that requires the use of a webcam. I would like to use my iPad to connect to a Hosted Virtual Machine through a Remote Desktop. I’ve tried Amazon Workspaces and Microsoft Azure, but neither of them detect my iPad’s webcam. Is there a different hosted virtual machine service that my iPad’s webcam will work on or are there some settings I can change to make it work? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: how is this a question for stack overflow?

Comment: I figured someone here might know the answer, so I asked.